# Take out all values from list of mappings

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to change below

```
[{'course_id': '8'}, {'course_id': '16'}]
```

to

```
['8','16']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a list comprehension:

```
[x['course_id'] for x in data]
```

Or using [**`operator.itemgetter`<sup>[docs]</sup>**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
map(itemgetter('course_id'), data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on phant0m's answer here's a speed comparison of the two variations:

```
import timeit
import operator
setup = "data = [{'course_id': '8'}, {'course_id': '16'}]; import operator"

print timeit.timeit( "[x['course_id'] for x in data]", setup, number=1000000 )
# [x['course_id'] for x in data]
# Result: 0.219176683582

print timeit.timeit( "map(operator.itemgetter('course_id'), data)", setup, number=1000000 )
# map(operator.itemgetter('course_id')
# Result: 0.476915375646
```

With a longer dictionary the difference gets smaller:

```
# [x['course_id'] for x in data]
# Result: 1.65939845357

# map(operator.itemgetter('course_id')
# Result: 1.85912657123
```

It's likely the overhead from the function calls.